# Google Place Autocomplete does not show any search result

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, google-places-api

I'm using the google place autocomplete. But when I'm trying to type in any single places into search bar, the result is blank and it prompt the below message to me when I click the search bar. (Before that was working properly able to search with result)

```
 2017-09-26 14:23:09.650 myApp Consumer[43113:735286] Google Maps SDK for iOS and Google Places API for iOS version: 2.4.30121.0
    2017-09-26 14:23:11.975813+0800 myApp Consumer[43113:735286] [MC] Error getting system group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles: 21
    2017-09-26 14:23:11.976028+0800 myApp Consumer[43113:735286] [MC] Failed to get profiles system group container
    2017-09-26 14:23:11.979185+0800 myApp Consumer[43113:735286] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

Below are some code,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.googleMapsView = GMSMapView(frame: self.mapView.frame)
    self.view.addSubview(self.googleMapsView)

    searchResultController = SearchResultsController()
    searchResultController.delegate = self
    gmsFetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher()
    gmsFetcher.delegate = self

    searchBar()
}


func searchBar() {
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)

        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
    }
```

Comment: Share some code or create a jsfiddle so that we can help you

Comment: @RashFlash I've added the code